# packet ordering in socket c++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am writing a c++ socket program for client and server ,should I keep the packets in a specific order or it will remain the same order they had been sent?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

TCP socket abstraction gives you a bi-directional ***reliable stream of bytes***, so data will arrive in the same order you send it. The caveat though is that TCP does not know about your ***application-level message boundaries*** - you have to make sure you know how to detect and buffer partial messages on the receiving side.

Comment: To be precise: you don't know what order the packets arrive in, but they will be presented to you via the API in the order they were originally sent.

Comment: @Nikolai you mean that the caveat is the data may be partitioned without knowing that , so not the all data may be sent to over the network?

Comment: @Paul so it is not required to give the message a specific order? it is API functionality?

Comment: I mean you should not expect one `write()` from the sender to correspond to exactly one `read()` on the receiver. Since TCP does its own packetization you might read more or less then one message, and it's your job to keep track of the message boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TCP, then packet ordering is handled by it. That means that if you open a socket and send A, B, and then C, the other socket's end will receive A, B, and then C.

On the other hand, if you're using UDP, then there is no such guarantee.